# It it possible for a MitM attacker to know when a browser has gone into incognito mode?

Tags: security, browser, internet-security, private-browsing

This may be better suited to security, but since it's about a specific feature of software, I thought I'd ask here.

Lets say that I am viewing a website, and I open a tab in incognito mode (unless applicable this question is browser agnostic). Is it possible for a MitM to explicitly know that I have gone into incognito?

To be clear, I understand that Incognito ONLY affects my personal computer as far as when and where data is saved, and that all *traffic* is visible to a MitM, and I am not asking about the content of what I am browsing, but only if a MitM could discern in some way that I was USING incognito mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As almost every website uses cookies: probably yes.

Like: in your first browser window(s) to the target website your browser will probably be sending the website's cookies to that site, and then suddenly the man in the middle sees traffic to the same website but without those cookies. (And after the first incognito request: with *other* cookie values for the incognito windows.)

Also, if incognito mode does not share the cache with the regular mode, then the man in the middle might see new requests for resources that you already received earlier. Such might also indicate a forced reload, but it surely might give the man in the middle some idea. (And for subsequent requests: different values for `If-Modified-Since` or `Etag` headers.)

(In case of a shared connection, this assumes the attacker knows which computer makes the requests, but [that might be easier than one thinks](https://panopticlick.eff.org/).)

Comment: Why the downvote? This seems like a reasonable way for a site operator to attempt detection of incognito mode.

Answer (score -1):

Incognito mode IS browser specific by definition because the main purpose of it is to tell Google to not record which sites you've visited on their servers. The other functions can easily be done in other browsers using other means. MitM attacks still work just the same. This is confirmed on the Google support page for this feature, which states:

> Be careful, because the websites you visit, your employer, or your 
>   service provider can still see your browsing activity, even in 
>   incognito mode.

These are exactly the people you need to worry about when it comes to MitM attacks (or the employees of these organizations).

[Source](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en)

I have not explicitly stated whether this means that MitM attackers can tell if incognito is on or off. I cannot provide proof of this one way or the other though because, to do so, I'd need to prove a negative. I can assert the positive statement, which is that it is possible to detect when Incognito mode is off and a person is using Chrome by looking at the extra chatter the browser is making to home base. If someone already knows that you only browse with Chrome, only then, could they assert that the lack of such chatter means that they are using Incognito mode.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to answer the question - That being if a MitM can tell if I'm using a form of private browsing. The question isn't concerned about if a MitM can see WHAT I'm browsing.

Comment: *"the main purpose of it is to tell Google to not record which sites you've visited on their servers"*--why do you think that's the main purpose? (Even more: why do you believe incognito mode stops Google from profiling you? That's a dangerous assumption.)

Comment: @Arjan Because, of all of the reasons given on the page which describes that feature, the only function that doesn't have alternative methods of access are those that report browsing data to Google for their data collection (as opposed to that which is sent to Google so that they can provide cloud services to the end user). Also, I didn't say what I believed, I'm only reporting what Chrome is telling us.

Comment: Nope. *"If you don’t want [Google] Chrome to save a record"* is not at all the same as *"tell Google to not record which sites you've visited on their servers"*. Also, non-Google browsers also have incognito modes. (And, like @Sidney already commented: this does not answer the question.)

Comment: *"by looking at the extra chatter the browser is making to home base"*--uhh, where did you get that from? This is just false information.

Comment: @Arjan The part where you disconnect yourself from Google is by not being logged into a Google account. They can still collect anonymous data but they will not be associating that anonymous data with your personal account (because you aren't signed in). Once signed into an account, the interface provides no means to browse while not signed in aside from Incognito mode. I highly doubt that any other current browser works like this.

Comment: You don't need to go incognito to not sign into Chrome. You're mixing Google with incognito modes. It's unrelated. (And thanks for that downvote.)

Comment: @Arjan You're simply wrong. Look up the word in Google. The very first result is for Chrome. Nothing else on the first 5 pages of results has anything to do with any browsers. Not saving your history is not all it's about. It was introduced in the exact same release as the profiles if you're still not convinced. The main purpose is to temporarily browse without reporting everything you're doing to Google; that is it. Once again, no other browser enforces that you stay connected to a Home server the way Chrome does and so no other browser has this feature.

Comment: This is called "InPrivate Browsing" in IE and "Private Browsing" in Firefox. As a note, if you happen to like Chrome but are bothered by the data being collected by Google during your usage, you might try Chromium. Reading http://lifehacker.com/5763452/what-data-does-chrome-send-to-google-about-me might also be interesting for you.

Comment: *"Look up the word in Google"*--ah, you're focusing on Google's name of this feature? I guess you missed the *"unless applicable this question is browser agnostic"* then. (And using Google to prove your point made me giggle, [thanks](http://www.bing.com/search?q=incognito+browsing). ☻) As for releases, as far as I know: profiles were introduced in Chrome 16, December 2011. Incognito mode has been available since the very first release in 2008.

Comment: Ah, maybe you're just saying *"If you're logged in to Chrome, in which case it will send your profile and browsing details to Google's servers, then a man in the middle might see that such data is no longer sent after starting Chrome's incognito mode."* And then indeed you might have a point. (I still don't agree with many of the details you wrote, but that does not warrant a downvote then.)

Comment: I thought I was being clear about that. It is also that specific difference that makes Incognito mode different than 'Private Browsing' in other browsers.